# Checking whether string ends with given string in clojure

Tags: string, clojure

I have created a function to check whether or not my first string ends with a second string.

In Java we have ready made method to check this, but in Clojure I failed to find such a method so I written custom function as follows:

```
(defn endWithFun [arg1 arg2] 
    (= (subs arg1 (- (count arg1) (count arg2)) (count arg1)) arg2))
```

Outputs:

```
> (endWithFun "swapnil" "nil")
true
> (endWithFun "swapnil" "nilu")
false
```

This is working as expected.

I want to know, is there a similar alternative?
Also in my case, I compare case sensitively. I also want to ignore case sensitivity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the native Java `endsWith` directly in Clojure:

```
(.endsWith "swapnil" "nil")
```

See http://clojure.org/java_interop for some more details.

You can then naturally compose this to get case insensitivity:

```
(.endsWith (clojure.string/lower-case "sWapNIL") "nil")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking out for. now i can see i can use java api of `String` class by using `(. )`, i tried `(subs "swapbil" 1 4)` and `(. "swapnil" substring 1 4)` both gives ans **wap** , is there any performance degrade if i use java in clojure? or both will have same performance.

Comment: I imagine that the performance should be comparable. You can build a quick micro-benchmark if you are worried.

Comment: In general the only performance penalty you might suffer using Java in Clojure is the use of reflection to look up a method at runtime if an object's class can't be inferred at compile-time. The `clojure.string` functions all use type hints to avoid reflection, so there should be negligible performance difference between the Clojure and Java versions.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement @kotarak.

Comment: @EmilSit You are welcome. In fact the new notation is translated to the old one. And in macros the old one is quite useful at times. However in the source the new one looks more clojurey. Similar: `(Constructor. a b c)` vs. `(new Constructor a b c)`

Answer (score 6):

Clojure 1.8 introduced an `ends-with?` function in [clojure.string](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.string-api.html#clojure.string/ends-with?), so now there is a native function:

```
> (ends-with? "swapnil" "nil")
true
> (ends-with? "swapnil" "nilu")
false
```

Again, just apply `lower-case` if you want case insensitivity.